# Web App using Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: .net, html, windows-phone-7, emulation

am developing a web app, the original webpages are using HTML5, when i  run the application on the Emulator the web browser does not show the pages properly!

how can i test HTML5 pages for windows phone?
 i'm using VS2010, WP7.1, and the default Emulator that is installed using the SDK

Comment: P.S When I go to html5test.com on IE on Emulator I get the result of 141 out of 475. Plus 5 bonus points whatever that means.

Comment: I don't understand your question. 'How can I test HTML5 pages for windows phone' -> Well, you said it: with the emulator. Note that WP7's HTML rendering engine is mostly the same as IE9's, so most of  the tests can be done on the desktop version of IE9. It just leaves layout issues, to test with WP7's smaller screen.

Comment: through the app,when am trying to browse a webpage that contains any html5 related thing, nothing appears, the webbrowser is absolutely empty, when am browsing webpage with no html5 it appears normally!!! am i making my popint clear?

Comment: How about when you test it in a desktop Windows version of IE9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no special 'trick' to testing for IE within WP7. You have the emulator, which is the only real tool at your disposal. Testing on desktop IE9 is probably the closest experience you can have to the phone browser. However, there are differences. These resources might help:

[IE9 Mobile Developer Overview](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/09/22/ie9-mobile-developer-overview.aspx) - lists the various CSS / HTML5 features supported by WP7

[Designing IE9 mobile](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2011/09/22/designing-ie9-mobile-putting-sites-in-the-spotlight.aspx) - describes how to optimise websites for WP7

[The differences between IE9 desktop and IE9 on WP7](http://www.ubelly.com/2011/11/the-differences-between-ie9-on-the-desktop-and-ie9-on-wp7/) - does what it says on the tin.

Comment: the "There is no special 'trick' to testing for IE within WP7" is more than enough for me, your links are very informing :), 
 i got to dig lil deeper i guess, thanks..